# I have created a module using ultimate module creator,but it is not showing on the magento backend

Tags: magento

I have created a module using ultimate module creator,but it is not showing on the magento
back end.
I have cleared the magento cache and done the re-indexing also
i have checked in the file,its present in the local folder and is enabled
but still not showing in backend

Comment: What version of the module creator are you using?

Comment: the latest one 
version 1.9

Comment: Did you disable compilation? (if it's enabled).

Comment: yes,but still can't able to fix this issue

Comment: Send the file `var/modulecreator/package/[Namespace]_[Module].xml` to the developer (that's me). This way your module can be recreated and tested. You will find the e-mail address in any of the files of the module creator.

Answer (score 0):

Check all the config file (i.e. config.xml) and ACL permissions (in adminhtml.xml) if you are not able to see anything in admin panel.

Comment: I am creating a small module using a ultimate module creator I want to show the attribute value instead of associated product.. for example I want to show the attribute color values like red,green,blue ... instead of products name

can u help me ?

Comment: Brar Can you please elaborate your requirement, where do you want to show these attributes? Are you talking about configurable product?

Comment: can u tell mee,how can i  make seo friendly url's
b'z now the module generating this url
storebrand_storebrand/storebrands
but i want my url to have "advertiser"

thanks